# WPF how make StackPanel Scrollable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, stackpanel

in a stackpanel i add some labels from code behind at runtime: i want make the stackpanel scrollable. In the xaml file i have:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="592,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="188" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelVistaProfiloTessera" Height="292" Width="170"/>

</ScrollViewer>
```

In the code behind i add some label to the stackpanel:

```
for(.....)
{
    stackPanelVistaProfiloTessera.Children.Add(new Label {....});
}
```

Why the stackpanel isn't scrollable? How can i resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Put `ScrollViewer` inside `StackPanel`.

Comment: You could use a ListBox instead. It will scroll automatically.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Remove height and width from stackpanel..rest is working fine here.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Green" Height="299" Margin="592,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="188" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelVistaProfiloTessera"  Background="RoyalBlue" >
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5">label1</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Output look like this.

[image]

and you can set margin to stackpanel if you are using height and width for design purpose.