# how to scroll stackpanel in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to scroll items in stackpanel added programmatically, but it's not working:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" >
    <StackPanel x:Name="options" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="760" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,0,0,0">
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

is there any error?

Comment: "It's not working" doesn't explain the problem. What is actually happening?

Comment: nothing is happening i tried to scroll it, but it doesn't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168565/wpf-how-make-stackpanel-scrollable/23168683#23168683

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify the horizontal visibility of the `ScrollViewer`. Set it to any value other than `Disabled` (the default) and it will work:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```